# Break back a concatenated List or Data Frame, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data frames that I concatenate together  as

```
X=[X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10]
```

I wanted to ask if it is possible to keep some indexes on where they are getting concatenated to break them back and get again X_1, X_2,... and so on

the reason for that is that I am creating unique categorical variables for some gps coordinates (in reality these are encoded as geohashes strings). The code below creates for all entries to X unique categories for specific strings (if I am not wrong). A geohash looks like u0m6cne and the code below will turn it to a categorical number like 39.

```
Geo_as_Category=pd.Series(X['Geohash'], dtype="category")
X['GeohashFeature']=Geo_as_Category.cat.codes
```

After this process is completed I would like to turn X back to the initial data sets, as X_1,X_2 and so on.

Is there a nice way to do that without overcomplicating things?

Thanks 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You want `keys`

Easiest way is to use a dictionary

```
df = pd.concat(dict(enumerate(X)))
```

If you want your list back

```
[d.xs(k) for k, d in df.groupby(level=0)]
```

Comment: great answer thanks. Unfortunately I can not vote yet.
For my example I slightly edited the code to
           X=pd.concat(dict(enumerate([X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10])))
and then 
         [X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10]=[d.xs(k) for k, d in X.groupby(level=0)]